# Не авторизуется при подключении к Team Foundation Server

Tags: аутентификация, tfs

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs_name:5050/tfs");
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthentication();

WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Comment: Какой-то эксепшн генерируется?

Comment: Код работает и все запускается, проблема появляется когда выводится окно, где нужно ввести логин и пароль. Я ввожу верные данные, но сервер не принимает их. Хотя, если я ввожу их, не используя код, то все норм.

Comment: Рекомендую не тратить время на данный подход, а сразу использовать rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно не хватает имени коллекции в адресе:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs_name:5050/tfs");
```

Обычно выглядит так:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs_name:5050/tfs/DefaultCollection");
```

Answer (score 1):

В продолжение темы.

Не рекомендую использовать данный подход, т.к. он будет отключен в скором будущем [Announcing the deprecation of the WIT and Test Client OM at Jan 1, 2020](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/05/21/announcing-the-deprecation-of-the-wit-and-test-client-om-at-jan-1-2020-2/)

Лучше использовать подключение через REST, клиент можно найти через nuget пакеты: [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.131.1). Пример использования можно посмотреть [здесь: VSTS Rest Api. 1. Подключение к сервису](https://ashamray.wordpress.com/2018/08/30/vsts-rest-api-1-connect/)